# How do you decide on a suitable frame rate for an Android game built in Unity(2020.1)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

As there are mobile phones with refresh rate of 120Hz(eg; One Plus 8) and low end phones which has much lower refresh rates, what is the best frame rate to set for an Android mobile game built with Unity?
My game frame rate was set at 30fps and it ran sluggishly on the Oneplus 8. When I did another build with a fps of 120, the game ran smoothly.
Is it ok to set the frame rate to 120 for all phones or not set the frame rate at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can set the framerate to 120. If a device can't perform a 120 fps then it will just run at maximum fps of what it can do.

Comment: Wouldn't it run at the maximum frame rate even if I did not set the frame rate at all?

Comment: No. From the unity's document : 

- On mobile platforms the default frame rate is less than the maximum achievable frame rate due to the need to conserve battery power. Typically on mobile platforms the default frame rate is 30 frames per second.

- All mobile platforms have a fix cap for their maximum achievable frame rate, that is equal to the refresh rate of the screen (60 Hz = 60 fps, 40 Hz = 40 fps, ...). Screen.currentResolution contains the screen's refresh rate.